# Not able to prepare NpgsqlCommand?

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

I am currently trying to make a prepared command, but for some reason am I getting this error

```
Hint    "There is a column named \"entity_id\" in table \"temp_country\", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query." string
```

when I do this

```
connection.Execute(@$"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_{entityName}; select * into temp_{entityName} from {entityName}");
var getNewIdSql =
    $"INSERT INTO \"temp_{entityName}\"(entity_id) values(@entity_id) RETURNING entity_id";
NpgsqlCommand insertEntry = new NpgsqlCommand(getNewIdSql, connection, transaction);
insertEntry.Prepare();
```

and I am ont sure what I am doing wrong here? because table exist, and has the column? so I am not sure why this is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is indeed misleading, but the problem is simply that you haven't added an NpgsqlParameter for `entity_id` to the NpgsqlCommand before calling Prepare:

```cs
NpgsqlCommand insertEntry = new NpgsqlCommand(getNewIdSql, connection);
var param = new NpgsqlParameter("entity_id", NpgsqlDbType.Integer);
insertEntry.Parameters.Add(param);
insertEntry.Prepare();
```